# How to show result into a textarea comming from an Ifram with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I i have an iframe in which i am uploading a text file and after uploading reads its contents which are only urls. the problem is that i am unable to show the result in a textarea where this iframe is called someone please get me out from this. my code is below.
this is the code of i frame.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(this).parent().find("#social_media_urls").val("<?php echo $links?>");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and blow is the html where i want to show the result.

```
<div class="tabs-content" id="tab_social_urls">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="left"> Upload URLs (csv): </div>
      <div class="rite">
        <iframe id="uploadFile" src="<?php echo "includes/iframe_upload_file.php" ;?>"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="left"> Current URLs: </div>
      <div class="rite">
        <textarea name="social_media_urls" id="social_media_urls" cols="" rows="">

                                                </textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

i want to show the result in text area.

Comment: it'd be a lot easier if you didn't have to use an iframe. can't you just put the urls in the DOM of the same document? if it's just a list of URLs you're getting back, it seems like you could just fetch those via ajax and write them into the same spot in the DOM. iframe should only be used if you need it. this doesn't seem like the proper use of iframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you use like this  you may set value in the text area

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#social_media_urls").val("<?php echo $links?>");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had that issue, I solved using something like:

```
parent.$('#social_media_urls') ...
```

Comment: Absolutely true. And since he's loading the iframe with a relative path, I think it's the case.